# Laravel session resets after reload

Tags: php, session

My laravel session doesn't seem to be working.

When I reload the page all session data seems to be lost.

I.e:

- CSRF-Token
- Session::put('key', 'value');
- Session::get('key');

### CSRF Token

Login form:

```
Session::token() => Cr3TwtQOWg6O2zV8rfksTQfqwEb3NxXjmIiA54kX
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Cr3TwtQOWg6O2zV8rfksTQfqwEb3NxXjmIiA54kX">
```

But when the form is submitted:

```
Session::token() => gIDZJ4aP3zw3cdZm3BjRHo05TMWrIfNiiBjSIfni
Input::get('_token') => Cr3TwtQOWg6O2zV8rfksTQfqwEb3NxXjmIiA54kX
```

### Session::put / get

Login form:

```
Session::put('token_session_test', 'This is a string that should verify that the session works');

Session::get('token_session_test') => This is a string that should verify that the session works
```

When submitted:

```
Session::get('token_session_test') =>
```

Does anyone have ideas for why this happens or how to fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turns out the config was set to save cookies in a subdomain which this server was no longer under, therefore it was never reused, and a new session is generated on every request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a route group in routes.php.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function()
{
    Route::post(....); // here you can add login post where you can validate username and password
});
```

In login view you need to add **{{ Form::token(); }}** with blade

The csrf token is generated for every refresh.